# Mercurial - team review of changeset prior to remote repo push

Tags: mercurial

We have multiple developers working on our app.

We'd like to review a developers code prior to pushing that to the remote repo.

How can we distribute the changeset for review without pushing it to the remote repo (and having other dev's pull and review from the remote repo)?

---

**Update**: Had thought about just having the developer [share](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) their local repository. Not sure exactly how to do this on Windows..  I see shared disk mentioned on the linked doc..  not clear how to set that up..

**Update 2**: Figured out that `hg serve` worked as a nice way to share the repo..  see answer below.

Comment: Have you considered using Kiln, which is Mercurial + +? It comes with Code Review capabilities built into the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We used [hg serve](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve) to allow the developer to share her repository using Mercurial's built in web server.  Other developers cloned their local repository then pulled in the changes in question from the developer's repo using `hg pull http://1.2.3.4:8000`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use a intermeditate *review* repo where developers `push` their code for review, and once checked, from that repo is pused to the remote repo.

**Update:** There is also a lot of [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_code_review) tools that can help you, or you may work with [Pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) and some tool like [one2merge](https://github.com/ifosch/one2merge) to aprove them after the reviewers see the changes and comment on them.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to emulate open-source projects and send out changesets for review via email.  Benefits include:

- No need for yet another repo/server
- The patch is sent for review via email, so any number of reviewers can be copied
- A traceable history of the code review is archived in email

See the [patchbomb](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PatchbombExtension) and [mbox](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MboxExtension) extensions for details.